# How to set Rabbitmq.config on Windows OS

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using Rabbitmq server 3.9.13 on windows.
When I runs Rabbitmq server, it saids

```
This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more
```

So I am going to edit the config file but I can not find where the file is located.
Is there someone know it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the config file path using the following command.

```
rabbitmq-diagnostics.bat status
```

The file was located in 'C:/Users/Your User/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advance.config'